# Has anyone done a scientific analysis of the "Ghost Radar" app for ios/android?

Tags: software, ghosts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can smartphone Apps detect EMF?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/can-smartphone-apps-detect-emf)

Hard to find anything scientific regarding this app on the interwebs...  Almost seems like search results have been manipulated to lower the rank of any sort of skeptical analysis.

> Ghost Radar® is a portable application designed to detect paranormal activity for the iPhone, iPod touch, iPads. Ghost Radar® attempts to detect paranormal activity by using various sensors on the device on which it is running. Like traditional paranormal detecting equipment Ghost Radar® employs sensors that measure electromagnetic fields, vibrations, and sounds. However, traditional paranormal equipment can be easily fooled when simple mundane bursts of normal electromagnetic fields, vibrations and sounds occur. Ghost Radar® sets itself apart by analyzing the readings from sensors giving indications only when interesting patterns in the readings have been made. Ghost Radar® also includes a voice to let you know when interesting words have been detected. Please note we offer no guarantees of accuracy or any warranties, therefore, since results from this application cannot be verified scientifically the app should be used for entertainment purposes.

[source](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ghost-radar/id314696635?mt=8)

I'd like to know if anyone has done a writeup or reverse engineered the code to find out what the app is doing programmatcially.

Comment: any links to the app?

Comment: Closed this one as the other is more general - if you think this particular app is any different explain why and I'll reopen :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't find the other question for some reason :)